# Php foreach in_array keeps returning false

Tags: php, arrays

I built a foreach which loops through a specific folder and gets an array:

```
foreach ($watchFolder as $key => $value) {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($value);
  echo '</pre>';
  if((in_array('xml', $watchFolder))) {
    echo "true";
  } else {
    echo "false";
  }

  foreach ($value as $key => $valueSub) {
    $currentWatchPath2 = $currentWatchPath . '\\' . $key;
    foreach ($valueSub as $content) {
      $currentWatchPath3 = $currentWatchPath2 . '\\' . $content;
    }
  }
}
```

If I print out the `$watchfolder` I get this:

```
Array (
  [test] => Array([videos] => Array()
                  [xml] => Array())

  [test2] => Array([json] => Array([0] => test.json)
                   [videos] => Array())
)
```

If I try this:

```
dd(in_array('xml', $value));
```

it returns `null`, whereas it should return true or?

I am really confused at the moment, so I appreciate every tips and suggestion.

Comment: I think `in_array` will only get values not keys.

Comment: `in_array` only checks the values, not the keys. `array_key_exists()` might help.

Comment: To check the key you can check like this: `isset($value['xml'])`

Comment: whops right, but still keeps returning false

Comment: edited my question

Comment: What is dd method? I don't see in you question what dd does.

Comment: if only you can post the array instead of the array result .The array result is useless.we can't create a simple fiddle with the array result

Comment: what excatly do you mean?

Comment: Why not use `array_key_exists`?

Answer (score 0):

`xml` is a key of `$value` array so I think you should check like this:

```
foreach ($watchFolder as $key => $value) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($value);
        echo '</pre>';
        if(isset($value['xml'])) { // <--- here is the changed.
            echo "true";
        } else {
            echo "false";
        }

        foreach ($value as $key => $valueSub) {

            $currentWatchPath2 = $currentWatchPath . '\\' . $key;

            foreach ($valueSub as $content) {

                $currentWatchPath3 = $currentWatchPath2 . '\\' . $content;

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: I think this worked, I will test around and check the answer if it keeps working

Comment: `isset()` will return to true even if that value is `''` or a blank space.

Comment: @aldrin27 Yes. That's true. If you wan to return false when it's empty or not set you can use: `!empty($value['xml'])`

Answer (score 0):

In replace of in_array('xml', $watchFolder), it would be used in_array('xml', $value)

```
foreach ($watchFolder as $key => $value) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($value);
    echo '</pre>';
    if((in_array('xml', $value))) {
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo "false";
    }

    foreach ($value as $key => $valueSub) {

        $currentWatchPath2 = $currentWatchPath . '\\' . $key;

        foreach ($valueSub as $content) {

            $currentWatchPath3 = $currentWatchPath2 . '\\' . $content;

        }

    }

}
```